# How do I get this ASP.NET routing to work properly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to write a really simple prototype of a CMS system using ASP.Net MVC 3.

The system has a single controller with two actions: show and create.

The format for the 'Show' action is meant to take up to 5 optional parts, e.g. domain.com/part1/part2/part3/part4/part5

The format for the 'Show' action is similar, but should have a leading 'create' part e.g. domain.com/create/part1/part2/part3/part4/part5

I have the following settings in my global.asax:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "CreatePageRoute",
        "create/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}",
        new
            {
                controller = "Page",
                action = "Create",
                part1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part5 = UrlParameter.Optional
            });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}",
        new
            {
                controller = "Page",
                action = "Show",
                part1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                part5 = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

If my 'Show' method fails to find a page matching the supplied path, it returns a 'not found' page that includes an options to create a new page with the supplied path.  This link is defined using the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Yes", "Create")
```

[the "Yes" represents the answer to the question "do you want to create a page for this path?"]

So when testing the 'Default' route, I see that my 'Show' action is called successfully for all of the following paths:
{empty}
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d/e

which is great.

However, the resulting 'create' link generated by the statement "@Html.ActionLink("Yes", "Create")" gives inconsistent results.  It seems to generate a different hyperlink depending on the length of the input.  The results are as follow:

For path "{empty}", the link offers "localhost{:port}/" - I was hoping for "localhost{:port}/create"

For path "/a", the link offers "localhost{:port}/" - I was hoping for "localhost{:port}/create/a"

For path "/a/b", the link offers "localhost{:port}/a" - I was hoping for "localhost{:port}/create/a/b"

For path "/a/b/c", the link offers "localhost{:port}/a/b" - I was hoping for "localhost{:port}/create/a/b/c"

For path "/a/b/c/d", the link offers "localhost{:port}/create/a/b/c/d" - which is what I was hoping for

For path "/a/b/c/d/e", the link offers "localhost{:port}/create/a/b/c/d/e" - which is what I was hoping for

Why does it only work when I supply "/a/b/c/d" or "/a/b/c/d/e"?

I know I'm being idiotic, please help me

Sandy

Comment: A while back I had a similar issue. Try changing `UrlParameter.Optional` to just `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that multiple optional parameters are causing the discrepency.
How about:

```
    routes.MapRoute("Create5", "create/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Create", part5 = UrlParameter.Optional });
    routes.MapRoute("Create3", "create/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Create", part3 = UrlParameter.Optional });
    routes.MapRoute("Create1", "create/{part1}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Create", part1 = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute("Default5", "{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Show", part5 = UrlParameter.Optional });
    routes.MapRoute("Default3", "{part1}/{part2}/{part3}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Show", part3 = UrlParameter.Optional });
    routes.MapRoute("Default1", "{part1}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Show", part1 = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Many thanks, this does the trick nicely.  Also, the manner in which your solution reduced the number of routes required by judicious use of optional parameters was illuminating.  Thanks for helping me.